# find symbolic tensor elements in another tensor one by one

Tags: python, loops, tensorflow, tensor

I have a model

```
def apk(x: SymbolicTensor, y: SymbolicTensor, k=10):
    """
    Computes the average precision at k.
    """
#here I need to find number of elements x, existed in y. 

@tf.function
def my_map_k(actual, predicted, k=10):
    """
    Computes the mean average precision at k.
    """
    results = tf.map_fn(lambda x: apk(x[0], x[1]), (actual, predicted), dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.reduce_mean(results)
""""
data preparation here. Every element of data X and Y is an array int[10]
""""
model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(300, input_shape=(1, 10)))  # input_shape=(None, 1)
model.add(Dense(10))
model.compile(loss=my_map_k, optimizer='adam', run_eagerly=True)
model.fit(X2, Y2, epochs=1000, batch_size=32)
```

In this model I need to develop custom loss function, that finds predicted elements into an Y elements, and calculates a binary difference between those arrays.

All my attempts to iterate or convert x, actual, y or predicted leads to one kind of error - "operation not supported by the symbolic tensor"
I will appreciate if somebody can show me how to find elements one symbolic tensor in another one.
I've already tried this:

```
    Compare = tf.reduce_any(int(x[:, None]) == int(y))
    exists = tf.math.count_nonzero(comparison_matrix)
    return float(exists) / float(min(len(x), k))
```

or this

```
    score = tf.math.count_nonzero(tf.reduce_any(int(x[:])==int(y[:]), axis=-1))
    return float(score) / float(min(len(x), k))
```

And had zero losses all the time...
PS: Casting to int() needs because the actual tensors are integer, but the predicted tensors are float.
Upd:

```
def apk(x: SymbolicTensor, y: SymbolicTensor, k=10):
        exists = tf.math.count_nonzero((x == tf.transpose(tf.cast(y, tf.int64))))
    return float(exists) / k
```

Same results - loss: 0.0000e+00

Answer (score 1):

I found a working solution:

```
def apk(x: SymbolicTensor, y: SymbolicTensor, k=10):
    score = tf.math.count_nonzero((x == tf.transpose([tf.cast(y, tf.int64)])))
    return float (k-score)/k
```